# How to format numbers on Android

Tags: java, android

i am learning to program mobile aplications on Android. My first app is a unit converter. Everithing is working for now, but i have a question about formating numbers. I hava this code to get text from buttons and to convert the appropriet output:

```
if (bPrevodZ.getText() == "milimeter"){
    if (bPrevodDo.getText()=="kilometer"){
        String PomocnaPremenna = jednotkaZ.getText().toString();
        double cisloNaPrevod = Double.parseDouble(PomocnaPremenna);
        cisloNaPrevod = cisloNaPrevod*0.0000001;
        vysledok.setText(Double.toString(cisloNaPrevod));
    }
```

The final result is "cisloNaPrevod", but i have problems to show a good format of that number. For example: 
12345 mm = 0,0012345 km this is good right ? :)

but if i convert:
563287 mm = 0.05632869999999995  this is bad :) i need it to show 0.0563287

Thx for any help

Comment: **Never** compare strings with `==`, use `.equals();`. Why? Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use String.format:

```
String.format("%.6f", cisloNaPrevod);
```

Comment: I think it would be %.7f rather than %.6f, but correct nonetheless :)

Comment: Thx for the quick answer, but how can i use it in my code ? :)

Comment: Use it instead of your Double.toString() call

Comment: Now i have a new problem: if i convert 55 ly to meters it will show 5.203E17 but i need to show the whole number  520340175991944000

Answer (score 2):

If you want your number to always have 6 significant figures, use

```
vysledok.setText(String.format("%.6g", cisloNaPrevod));
```

giving the result `0.0563287`.

If you want to round to 6 numbers after the decimal place, use

```
vysledok.setText(String.format("%.6f", cisloNaPrevod));
```

giving the result `0.056329`.

Here's some good resources that cover number formatting:

- [Floating-point cheat sheet for Java](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/java/)
- [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 1):

If it's something you're going to do often, perhaps you should use `DecimalFormat`.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#######");
```

Then call:

```
df.format(someDoubleValue);
```